# Handling Networking on Android

Tags: android, networking, standards, android-development

While doing Android development. There is really no clear way of doing network operations, sending and receiving data.

Currently I am handing it using `HttpsURLConnection` and having streams to build a request and response.

But I've seen on Android developers under Connectivity. Transmitting data using either [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/) or [Cronet](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/cronet/).

I've created a test application using Volley and it seems straight forward. However Volley requires the `Context` to run meaning it's now attached to the Android Framework. So sticking with MVVM it doesn't really fit.

I have also read about [*headless* Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting#HeadlessFragment) which is a `Fragment` that contains an inline `AsyncTask` class to handle networking

I could continue using my `HttpsURLConnection DataOutputStream` and `InputStreamReader`.
Then MVVM and unit testing can still work. There just doesn't seem like a standard way of doing this.

I am just looking to see if there is a more *standard* way of handling networking or not?

Comment: Any special reason for not using Retrofit?

Comment: @rcosteira No specific reason. I actually haven't really heard of it before! I will have to check it out!

Comment: It’ll probably solve your problem :) no Android stuff needed. You can isolate it completely. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using URLConnection and building streams just like you, but it does seem discouraged by Google. For example, you need

```
         android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

To use HTTPURLConnection now (as of 8.0 I believe), which is a hassle when your application is sending benign junk. That was a random break I didn't need.

I still think streams, in an ASyncTask, are the way to go. You can use a third party library like Volley but you never know when Android is going to break it. At least if they break streams like in the above example, you can typically fix it quickly. They're never going to completely drop streams and ASyncTask.

Comment: Your application is never sending benign junk